# Custom layout for page 404 in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I want to change default layout for 404 page in cakephp 3.x .I know I can change it from src/Templates/Error/error400.ctp file but what I want is to load css from my theme from plugins/Theme/webroot/ not from default webroot.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plugin syntax for loading css file from plugin.

```
echo $this->Html->css('DebugKit.toolbar.css');
```

[Source > Linking to CSS Files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-css-files)